# Is this Codeigniter code correct?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just started looking at PHP Frameworks after spending loads of wasted time doing everything from scratch. I thought I would give Codeigniter a go after a friend recommended it to me.

I worked through the first tutorial and there were no issues but I'm getting stuck with the second one.

At first my code was identical to the tutorial:

```
<?php


class Blog extends CI_Controller{


    function Blog()
    {

        parent::CI_Controller();

        $this->load->scaffolding('entries');
    }


    public function index(){

        $data['title'] = "My Blog Title";
        $data['heading'] = "An intresting title";


        $data['todo'] = array('create media player','design site','finish project');

        $this->load->view('blog_view',$data);
    }
}

?>
```

But I got an internal server error. After looking at the user guide it shows a different way for using the constructor.

I changed the code to the document spec.

```
<?php


class Blog extends CI_Controller{


    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->scaffolding('entries');
    }




    public function index(){

        $data['title'] = "My Blog Title";
        $data['heading'] = "An intresting title";


        $data['todo'] = array('create media player','design site','finish project');

        $this->load->view('blog_view',$data);
    }
}

?>
```

But I still get an internal error. I don't know if my code is wrong or I misconfigured something else. Some advice would be good, thanks.

Edit: 
To clarify - I only get an internal error when I add the constructor to the class.

Comment: You can get internal error when webserver is misconfigured. Does the rest of your app work normaly?

Comment: Yes it's only when I had the constructor it doesn't work - I will edit the question.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? This is important for others trying to find answer to your same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will most likely because you're trying to load `scaffolding` in the latest version of CodeIgniter.

Scaffolding has been [depreciated](http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/changelog.html) since version 1.6. It was [*removed*](http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/changelog.html) in 2.0, and the latest version is now 2.0.2

In terms of which of your provided snippets to use, the latter form of declaring a  constructor (`__construct`) is preferred over using the Class name (`Blog`). This method is also consistent with the Core Classes of CodeIgniter since 2.0.

As an aside, I've got no idea why CodeIgniter are including such out-of-date samples in their tutorials. EllisLab's seem to have lost total interest in the CI project recently, which is a shame :(

Answer (score 0):

Internal error means there's mis-server configuration.

Usually .htaccess file or apache settings. Try this:

1. Enable rewrite module in apache.
2. Make sure .htaccess file is configured correctly. It should look like this: https://gist.github.com/ce2914e79193896590bc

This also removes index.php, which you should look into.